# Unable to use Django Authenticate

Tags: python, django

I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError at /auth/
authenticate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

I am using Django and also Django Rest Framework.

The HTTP POST looks like this:

```
{
    "username": "HelloUser",
    "password": "Hello123"
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def authenticate(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    user = authenticate(username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password'])
    if user is not None:
        return Response({'Status': 'Authenticated'})
    else:
        return Response({'Status': 'Unauthenticated'})
```

**URLS**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'create/', views.create),
    url(r'retrieve/', views.retrieve),
    url(r'auth/', views.authenticate),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should not use the name of the view as **authenticate** as it is getting mixed with Django auth's authenticate 
And second, you don't need **self** parameter in authentication view i.e. **def authenticate_user(request)**
Update your code like this:

**VIEW**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def authenticate_user(request):
    print(request.data)
    user = authenticate(username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password'])
    if user is not None:
        return Response({'Status': 'Authenticated'})
    else:
        return Response({'Status': 'Unauthenticated'})
```

And your urls.py will be updated as per the view's name:

**URLS**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'create/', views.create),
    url(r'retrieve/', views.retrieve),
    url(r'auth/', views.authenticate_user),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```